# What are some good pages to redirect users to if they are using an old browser?

Tags: web, browser-support

Such as this one: http://www.webstandards.org/upgrade except it's just awful and is way out of date (use Netscape 7? really?)

I am going to require IE9+ and the latest versions of the rest of the browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: a polite method would be to redirect them to the latest version of whatever browser they're using. If it's an old/discontinued browser, or one universally derided, you can have some fun and redirect them elsewhere. "Oh, I see you're using AOL. Please try trainingwheels.com instead".

Comment: Best page to send them to: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Comment: @Marc B: no, because (1) a user may switch to another "brand" altogether, i.e. using Netscape 4, switching to IE10 ;) and (2) would be nice to give them some explanation before redirecting to any download page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://browsehappy.com/ is probably my favourite. I probably wouldn't redirect though. Maybe a popover/modal with the link in it? A little less militant.

Comment: Beautiful one. I wonder if it looks right in, say, Netscape 4? :) Just kidding, of course it's a good one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the user when using your site to an upgrade page can be **quite frustrating** for the user (also, the number of users who actually upgrade from their favorite "old"  browser is lower than we'd hope.)

I would suggest displaying a **[dialog](http://www.browser-update.org/#install)** urging him/her to upgrade to use the full site, while displaying a basic HTML-only (or scaled up mobile) site.

`http://www.browser-update.org/` helps you display an unobtrusive notification, urging the user to upgrade.